# Fetch Data from page and display on same page without refreshes

Tags: php, jquery

I have a condition that i have to post the different values of checkbox to *page2.php* as well as display the value on same page. How do i do?

**Page1:**

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input name="date1" type="checkbox" value="" id="1" />
<input name="date2" type="checkbox" value=""  id="2"/>
</form>

$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'page2.php',
        data: data,   
        success:function(html){

        }
    });
```

**Page2:**

```
<?php
    $date1 = POST_['date1'];
    $date2 = POST_['date2'];

    echo  $date1;
    echo  $date2;
?>
```

Comment: ...post to page2.php and display the updated values on page1.php. I'm afraid I'm a bit confused, is the second Page1 supposed to be Page2?

Comment: My scenario is post data to page2 for further usage and on page1 just want to display what user selected,pls see link http://s7.postimage.org/3zbf1ucwb/image.jpg,i want this,i did it via jquery but with jquery how to transfer to second page.The given image link is page1

Comment: In regards to your JSfiddle: your inputs need names (and you may want to set their values to 1)

Comment: And in any case, judging by the pattern of your previous posts, this is really starting to turn into something you should either A) post on the Code Review StackExchange site, or B) hire a freelancer to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing the second "Page1" is actually Page2

There you have an error, it should be $_POST['date1']. And as commented, you may first check if it is set with:

```
if (isset($_POST['date1']))
```

And in you Page1, lets add a container like

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

Then inside `<script></script>`:

```
$(function(){
    $('input').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'PAGE.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),   
            success:function(html){
               $('#result').html(html);
            }
        });
    });
});​
```

This sets the returning result from page2.php inside the element with id "result"

Edit: Here is a JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rF4qg/

In the one you commented there was some errors with closing braces. See that I've added a name to the checkboxes and that the data sent is formed by serializing the form.

Comment: I was writing my own answer, but this touches on a few of the things I was mentioning. You may want to include that the AJAX needs to be within `<script></script>` tags, and that setting `$date1 = $_POST['date1'];` may cause a Notice error (fixed by first calling isset() on $_POST['date1'])

Comment: Good edits, Pablo. Judging by the screenshot posted in the question comments, there may be more than one form (which would throw off the AJAX), but with the information provided so far, this is a very good solution.

Comment: @PABLO http://jsfiddle.net/HbWUu/2/ .Pls look into this and tell what i did wrong

Comment: @CreativeSolution You should select jQuery as the Framework (left menu)
Also in data you have ???, there you should put the data you want to send to the server. This data may be the result of what a user put in a form (using something like $('#formId').serialize() ) or you can write your own object.
Also the POST will never work inside jsfiddle.net, so you can't try the success function. It would be better if you have a php server to test it all.

Comment: i know php wont work on fidde,just to give you what i did,any code mistake??

Answer (score 0):

page.php

```
<?php
    $date['date1'] = $_post['date1'];
    $date['date2'] = $_post['date2'];

    echo  $date
?>
```

Another page

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input name="date1" type="checkbox" value="" id="1" />
<input name="date2" type="checkbox" value=""  id="2"/>
</form>

$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'page2.php',
        data: data,   
        success:function(html){
                alert(html[0]);
                alert(html[1]);
        }
    });
```

**Note:**
alert(html[0]);

alert(html[1]);

you can put this values anywhere

Comment: +0: While you have good ideas regarding how to get the data from page2.php, you kinda sorta missed the incorrect `$_POST['date1']` call. In addition, you need some way to call the AJAX, either by onclick methods for the inputs or an onsubmit on the form